# Brother 8880DN Scanning

Tags: networking, printer, network-printer

We have a client with a  Brother MFC 8880DN connected up to their server via USB and shared out, which is printing fine and all is well.

It's really a short question more so than anything - in order for users to scan from their PC, I assume it would need to be networked up and not connected via USB - and the same for Scan to Email?

At the moment I guess the only way it could scan would be to scan and store a local copy onto the server?

Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get a manual for your printer from [Brother](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public/eu/gb/en/doc/manual_index.html?reg=eu&c=gb&lang=en&prod=mfc8880dn_eu_as&dlid=&flang=English&type2=-1), it will tell you what you can and cannot do.

It appear that there are two methods, one is using the software provided with the printer/scanner to present an option on the scanners LCD screen as a ["Scan to:"](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/htmldoc/mfc/cv_mfc8890dw/gb/html/sug/chapter4.html) option.  The other method is via ["Internet fax and Scan to E-mail (E-mail server)"](http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/htmldoc/mfc/cv_mfc8890dw/gb/html/nug/chapter13.html)

In either case it appears that, yes, you need to have it configured on the network in order to scan to multiple machines.